# How to put multiple subfigures in one figure without overfull warning?

Tags: overleaf

```
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth]{Whole Tweets of 4 TopicsRetweeting Behaviourdaily.pdf}
                \caption{relative scaled retweets counts of human users and bots}
             \label{fig:2a}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth]{Whole Tweets of 4 TopicsRetweeting BehaviourdailyReScaled.pdf}
                \caption{scaled retweets counts of human users and bots}
             \label{fig:2b}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth]{Whole Tweets of 4 TopicsRetweeting BehaviourdailyReScaled.pdf}
                \caption{scaled retweets counts of human users and bots}
             \label{fig:2b}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{caption}
    \label{fig 2:three graphs}


\label{fig: 2}       
\end{figure}
```

I have 10 subfigures want to align them each by each. But even if I put 3, they are overfulled on one page , how to make them show on 5 pages, each page 2 figures while auto-named as (a),(b),(c)..... of figure 2.

Comment: A `figure` environment can not automatically be split across pages. In order to get 5 pages with two subfigures each, while numbering the subfigures continuously, use 5 figure environments with a pair of subfigures each and use `\continuedfloat` in the second  to fifth `figure` environment.

Comment: In the horizontal direction you have , `\includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth]` which forces the image to be 30% larger than the available space, so naturally you will get overfull boxes.

Comment: @leandriis thanks! useful

Comment: You might take a look at the `floatrow` package, which defines a `subfloatrow` environment, with a simple syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following MWE, which places two subfigures on each page, while keeping the subfigure numbering continuous, might serve as a place to start from:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}
            \caption{relative scaled retweets counts of human users and bots}
            \label{fig:2a}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}
            \caption{scaled retweets counts of human users and bots}
             \label{fig:2b}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{figure caption}
        \label{fig:figure}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \continuedfloat
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}
            \caption{scaled retweets counts of human users and bots}
            \label{fig:2c}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}
            \caption{scaled retweets counts of human users and bots}
            \label{fig:2d}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{caption - continued from previous page}   
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \continuedfloat
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}
            \caption{scaled retweets counts of human users and bots}
            \label{fig:2e}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}
            \caption{scaled retweets counts of human users and bots}
            \label{fig:2f}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{caption - continued from previous page}   
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \continuedfloat
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}
            \caption{scaled retweets counts of human users and bots}
            \label{fig:2g}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}
            \caption{scaled retweets counts of human users and bots}
            \label{fig:2h}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{caption - continued from previous page}   
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \continuedfloat
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}
            \caption{scaled retweets counts of human users and bots}
            \label{fig:2i}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}
            \caption{scaled retweets counts of human users and bots}
            \label{fig:2j}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{caption - continued from previous page}   
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @projetmbc: I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I delete my comment.